# Taking common elements from 2 vectors in Lua

Tags: vector, lua

I have 2 vectors, lets say `v1 = (a,b,c,d,e)` and `v2 = (e,h,t,b,w)` and I want to get a third vector containing the common elements of `v1` and `v2`, in this case `v3 = (e,b)`

I've seen this is already asked in c++, but I cant see it for Lua.

Comment: You don't say that if an element `l` is repeated in `n` times in `v1` and `m` times in `v2`, you want `l` repeated `min(n,m)` in `v3`. Answers given already make different assumptions about the desired result and even if repetition is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

I assume when saying vectors, you mean `v1` and `v2` are both array-like tables, like this:

```
local v1 = {1,2,4,8,16}
local v2 = {2,3,4,5}
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
local v3 = {}

for k1,v1 in pairs(v1) do
    for k2,v2 in pairs(v2) do
        if v1 == v2 then
            v3[#v3 + 1] = v1
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take a pass through `v1` to build a lookup table for its values, then one pass through `v2` to find common values and add them to an output list:

```
function findcommon(a1, a2)
    local in_a1 = {} -- lookup table for a1's values
    for k,v in pairs(a1) do in_a1[v] = true end

    local common = {}
    local n = 0
    for k,v in pairs(a2) do 
        if in_a1[v] then 
            in_a1[v] = false
            n = n + 1
            common[n] = v
        end
    end

    return common
end
```

Given your example:

```
v1 = {'a','b','c','d','e'} 
v2 = {'e','h','t','b','w'}
common = findcommon(v1,v2)

print('('..table.concat(common,',')..')')  --> (e,b)
```

Comment: upvoted! how would you modify this to handle local e = {["f"]=10, ["g"]=11, ["h"]=12}
local f = {["h"]=11, ["h"]=12, ["i"]=13} where the output should be h 12

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Yu Hao's solution, the code below runs in linear time, but it does need extra memory, unless you can live with `v3` instead of insisting on `v4`. The time difference will probably only be noticeable for large input vectors, though.

```
local v1={1,2,4,8,16}
local v2={2,3,4,5}
local v3={}
for k,v in ipairs(v1) do v3[v]=false end
for k,v in ipairs(v2) do if v3[v]==false then v3[v]=true end end
for k,v in  pairs(v3) do if v3[k]==false then v3[k]=nil end end
local v4={}
local n=0
for k,v in  pairs(v3) do n=n+1; v4[n]=k end
for k,v in ipairs(v4) do print(k,v) end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to intersect larger vectors (arrays/sets), here's an attempt at an unmeasured premature optimization

```
local v1 = {1,2,4,8,16}
local v2 = {2,3,4,5}

local function intersect(t1,t2)

        local function make_lookup(t)
            local res={}
            for _,v in ipairs(t) do
                res[v]=true
            end
            return res
        end

        local smaller,larger
        if (#t1>#t2) then
            larger=t1
            smaller=t2
        else
            larger=t2
            smaller=t1
        end

        local lookup=make_lookup(smaller)

        local res={}
        for _,v in ipairs(larger) do
            if lookup[v] then
                res[#res+1]=v
            end
        end
        return res
end

local v1v2_intersected=intersect(v1,v2)
```

The internal lookup table is made of the smaller array table of the two. In "production" you would perhaps also want to check, whether you're dealing with correct input values

Comment: I understand the OP wants to see this implemented on vectors where it works but if the input was local e = {["f"]=10, ["g"]=11, ["h"]=12}
local f = {["h"]=11, ["h"]=12, ["i"]=13} it does not work

Comment: the code above only work for array-like tables, not dictionaries

Comment: @PirateApp if you substitute `ipairs` with `pairs`, it should work again: https://ideone.com/SWqx5t